# launch a shell from explorer with same working directory

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shell, windows-explorer

It would be handy if there was a hot key or context menu option that would launch a shell and `cd` me to whatever directory the focused explorer window is currently viewing.

Anyone have an idea?

-using windows 7 pro 64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bah! I found it.

`shift + right click` in the explorer window, and the context menu option appears.

Comment: Hm, that's cool. Must be a new Windows 7 feature. It's not happening in XP.

Comment: This also works in Vista.

Answer (score 1):

You might also like the [ContextConsole](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/) shell extension.

Features over the built-in support:

- Open an elevated command prompt
- Open a command prompt by clicking in the background of any open Explorer window -- no more going up a level to get a window to the directory you really want or mousing over to the much smaller target in the folder tree